# How to merge two branches with Git based on file differences instead of commits?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-merge, git-commit

I have a question regarding the merging process which can be quite difficult when using Git.

I'm familiar with most commands and got a good-running local repository on a different machine (on which I commit changes for our live-server at this moment). I also know the complete workflow within Git (Local Repos/Index/Workspace etc).

The problem is on my own development machine (standard Win8 machine).

I had a lot of trouble merging two branches and whatnot and finally solved all conflict with "git mergetool" command only to find out that not all files are merged.

**Situation**
I have my own branch on which I'm developing software, lets call it "myBranch". Then we have the "release" branch which is our final stage before we push to the live-server. I need to have all the code of "release" in "myBranch". They have a common ancestor at some point.

The thing right now is (after weeks of struggling getting everything to work, hence my frustration) there are pieces of code in "release" that aren't in "myBranch". Running "git merge" gives me the message "Already up-to-date".

**Question** 
Thus my question is: How can I let Git compare two branches based on actual file differences instead of commit differences so I can merge code I haven't got in my own branch yet, code that exists on the "release" branch but is not seen as a difference.

If my question is not complete enough please ask for additions and I'll try to make it as complete as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Code that isn't in your own branch could only *possibly* exist in other commits.  "Already up-to-date" means that you're trying to merge an ancestor of your own `HEAD` into itself and there can't *possibly* be anything to do.  Are you sure that your "release" is up-to-date with the server's?  Do you want to merge `origin/release`?

Comment: I pulled the "release" branch from the remote repository (bitbucket) so it's up to date. I understand what you mean but this is what I do after I pulled the release branch (while having myBranch checked out):
git merge release

Comment: Dumb question: have you committed your code?

Comment: My code is commited and pushed to the remote repository. This goes for myBranch since that's the branch I'm developing in. I find it really weird that a git merge does absolutly nothing when I'm clearly seeing differences in files.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood.  You actually *did* the merge (of the commits) but are not happy with the outcome and now want to take some changes, but cannot simply do that with `git merge` since you are (graphwise) up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, this is a very common situation in software development: Changes are done on a dev branch forked off a release branch that itself gets new commits in the mean-time. Assuming you are on 'myBranch', periodically rebase to 'release'.

```
$ git fetch --all
$ git rebase origin/release
```

If completed successfully, it will merge all changes in 'release' to 'myBranch' and it would look like you did your changes right on top of the latest 'release' branch.

Comment: I'll try it out. I already merged before, solving alot of conflicts but somehow it doesn't take all differences into the merge..

Comment: This is unlikely. It would be a critical Git bug if this were to happen. It could be that while resolving a lot of conflicts something got missed.